# Implement an Observer pattern in Dart

Tags: dart

I would like to implement an observer pattern in Dart but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Let's say I have a class:

```dart
class MyClass {

  String observed_field;

}
```

Now, whenever I change the field, I'd like to print "observed_field changed" string into the console. Pretty simple to do with a custom setter:

```dart
class MyClass {

  String _observed_field;

  get observed_field    => _observed_field;
  set observed_field(v) {
    _observed_field = v;
    print("observed_field changed");
  }

}
```

Now, of course, if I have not one, but many of those fields, I wouldn't want to create all those getters and setters. The obvious theoretical solution is to have them dynamically added to the class with something like this (not a working code, just an example of how I wish it looked):

```dart
class MyClass

  String  _observeable_field;
  String  _observeable_field_2;

  observe(#observeable_field, #observeable_field_2);

end
```

**Is it even possible?** Additionally, it would be super awesome to not have those fields defined above the `observe()` call, but rather  write something like:

```dart
observe(String: #_observeable_field, String: #_observeable_field_2);
```

So that those fields are declared automatically.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using the [Observe](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/observe.html) package. The example is taken from code comments in that package (and adapted to your example above).  Essentially, you annotate fields you want to be observable with the `@observable` annotation, and then listen for changes (which you trigger with the call to `Observable.dirtyCheck()`;

First, add the observable package in your `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
dependencies:
  observe: any
```

Then create a quick test program...

```dart
import 'package:observe/observe.dart';

class MyClass extends Object with Observable {
  @observable String observedField = "Hello";

  toString() => observedField.toString(); 
}

main() {
  var obj = new MyClass();

  // anonymous function that executes when there are changes
  obj.changes.listen((records) {
    print('Changes to $obj were: $records');
  });


  obj.observedField = "Hello World";

  // No changes are delivered until we check for them
  Observable.dirtyCheck();

  print('done!');
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Changes to Hello World were: [#<PropertyChangeRecord Symbol("observedField") from: Hello to: Hello World>]
done!
```

**Update** in response to comments...
Updating the example to omit the `Observable.dirtyCheck()` you can use a setter and `notifyPropertyChanged`, with the class instead mixing in `ChangeNotifier`

```dart
class MyClass2 extends Object with ChangeNotifier {

  String _observedField = "Hello";

  @reflectable get observedField    => _observedField;
  @reflectable set observedField(v) {
    _observedField = notifyPropertyChange(#observedField, _observedField, v);    
  }

  toString() => observedField;

}
```

Comment: I read another question on SO and it was suggest to use this `Observe` package. However I disliked that you actually had to call `Observable.dirtyCheck()` in order for the changes to be delivered. This sort of negates the whole point of observing something, if you still had to, basically, check for the changes manually.

Comment: If you take a look at the example on the API docs, it shows how you can avoid the dirtyCheck() by using the @reflectable annotation and notifyPropertyChange(). This is more akin to your example. http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/observe.html

Comment: @ChrisBuckett I see you write
**class MyClass extends Object with Observable**

is there a difference to
**class MyClass extends Observable**

Comment: and I guess since the class is now observable we don't need to create them like Lists or Maps **var obj = toObservable(new MyClass())**??

Comment: `toObservable` is only for lists and maps, no need to call it on other objects. To your previous comment: `class MyClass extends Object with Observable` is a mixin application and `class MyClass extends Observable` is inheritance. The former is useful if you want or have to inherit from another class than `Observable`. In Dart you can't inherit from more than one class. Here mixins come in handy because they provide some kind of limited multiple inheritance. If you want to stick with one style you can just always use the mixin variant for `Observable` even when you just extend `Object`.

Comment: There is no package as Observe _?